# How to increase quality of animation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, gganimate

I have this code below in R (not sure how to share the .csv file with you!!!), and I am trying to make it animated. I have two problems here:

1. The quality is very low when I render. If it is just a picture I could increase the quality using the `dpi` command.
2. I want to be able to see the name of each panel as something like the panel title that we see in `facet_grid`, but animated (so the title changes from one panel to another).

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
library(stringi)
library(abind)
library(dplyr)
library(directlabels)
library(gganimate)
Year = rep(2070:2099)
esi = read.csv('https://github.com/pouyakhl/rstudio/blob/main/SSP126_plot.csv', header = TRUE)
esi = esi %>% filter(Region %in% c('Crop Lands', 'Mountainous Lands', 'Natural Lands'))
gPlot <- ggplot(esi) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(30, 175), xlim = c(2071.5,2097.5))
gPlot

gPlot = gPlot + theme(legend.position = "top", text = element_text(size=25),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 25),panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="gray89", size = (0.3)),
                      panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="gray", size = (0.3)),
                      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 25),panel.border = element_rect(size = 2, linetype = 'solid', colour = "black", fill = NA)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Year", breaks=c(2072,2075,2078,2081,2084,2087,2090,2093,2096,2099)) +
  ylab(paste("Precipitation (mm)")) # + facet_grid(Region ~ Scenario)  # Year is the in X-axis title

gPlot

gPlot = gPlot + geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = esi[,14]), color = 'Blue',size = 0.9)
gPlot = gPlot + geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = 4.8 * esi[,15] - 4), color = 'Red',size = 0.9)

gPlot

gPlot = gPlot + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~((-1.308)*.+226.2), name = "BW and GW (mm)")) +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(vjust=2))
# ** "sec_axis()": is used to specify a secondary axis **
gPlot
ysmax <- rep(210, nrow(esi))

gPlot <- gPlot + geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year, ymin=(172.936-0.7645*esi[,17]), ymax=182), data=esi, fill="green", color='black', alpha = 0.6, size = 0.9)
gPlot <- gPlot + geom_ribbon(aes(x=Year, ymin=(172.936-0.7645*esi[,16]), ymax=182), data=esi, fill="deepskyblue2", color='black', alpha = 0.8, size = 0.9)

gPlot = gPlot +  transition_states(Region, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1.5) + ease_aes('sine-in-out') 
gPlot = animate(gPlot, duration = 10, fps = 10, width = 400, height = 350)

gPlot
anim_save('niceplot_anime.gif')
```

Comment: You might try adding `device = 'ragg_png'` in your `animate()` call, assuming you have the `ragg` package installed. (It provides better anti-aliasing than the defaults on windows computers.).  https://gganimate.com/reference/animate.html#arguments

Comment: Check out the help for `transition_states` in the Label Variables and Examples section for explanation for your 2nd question. https://gganimate.com/reference/transition_states.html#label-variables

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Regarding the quality, what you mentioned increased the quality a little bit. But, still, the axis numbers and titles and the overall quality are very low. Any other suggestions for increasing it?